# How to setup android ndk in jenkins on linux

Tags: jenkins, gradle, android-ndk

I have jenkins on ubuntu. Building worked fine until I started to use android ndk.
latest ndk is downloaded and extracted into /opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle
In /etc/profile.d/android.sh  is:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk-linux"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME="/opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle"
```

but I got still error:
:common:compileDebugNdk FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':common:compileDebugNdk'.
  NDK not configured.
  Download the NDK from http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/. Then add ndk.dir=path/to/ndk in local.properties.
  (On Windows, make sure you escape backslashes, e.g. C:\ndk rather than C:\ndk)

Answer (score 3):

The message says it all. You should add a text file `local.properties` to the project directory on the Linux machine, with one line

```
ndk.dir=/opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle
```

This file is usually in `.gitignore`, and Android Studio generates it automatically. But when you build your project in Jenkins, it does not open Android Studio.